# Moq does not contain a definition for ReturnAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock some API calls to a third-party service for unit testing purposes. I really just want this mocked function to return the same `RestEase.Response<...>` each time.

```
// Setup
var VeracrossMock = new Mock<IVeracrossAPI>(MockBehavior.Strict);
Func<List<VeracrossStudent>> func = () => new List<VeracrossStudent>() { new VeracrossStudent() { First_name = "Bob", Last_name = "Lob" } };
RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossStudent>> resp = new RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>("", new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK), func);

// Problem is on the line below
VeracrossMock.Setup(api => api.GetStudentsAsync(1, null, CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync<RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>>(resp);
```

It gives me a red underline and then claims the `ReturnsAsync` doesn't exist, or at least not with the arguments that I've given it.

```
Error CS1929 'ISetup<IVeracrossAPI, Task<Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>>>, Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>)' requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task<Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>>>'
```

How am I supposed to be using `ReturnsAsync`? Clueless as to how to mock this.

Comment: First check the version you are using and make sure it is up to date

Comment: @Nkosi I installed it yesterday, its version 4.8.3.

Comment: second the returns you are using does not match the arguments of the member being mocked. Remove the generic argument

Comment: @Nkosi yes it does, or I'm confused about what you are saying. `GetStudentsAsync` returns a `RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossStudent>>`.

Comment: Yes the member returns that but your use of the generic argument in the `ReturnsAsync` is what is breaking. Just do `.ReturnsAsync(resp)`. The method will infer the desired arguments.

Comment: I don't understand why but yeah, looks like that fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Click on the `ReturnsAsync` and go to definition and you will see why.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The generic argument being used does not match the arguments of the member being mocked.

Remove the generic argument

```
VeracrossMock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetStudentsAsync(1, null, CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(resp);
```

and the method will infer the desired generic arguments based on the member being mocked.

Comment: I have tried to write a second, almost entirely identical `.Setup` and am getting the same error again? Should I start a new question or edit this one?

Comment: @NilsGuillermin Show briefly in the comments here how you are calling `ReturnsAsync`

Comment: `VeracrossMock.Setup(_ => _.GetHouseholdAsync(101, CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(responseHamlet);`, where `responseHamlet` is a `RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossHousehold>>`. Basically very similar to original case.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin and you can confirm that `GetHouseholdAsync` returns a `Task<RestEase.Response<List<VeracrossHousehold>>>`

Comment: Ah no, it returned a 'container' type that had the type of responseHamlet inside of it. My bad, thank you for your patience.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin glad to help. Just take note that `ReturnsAsync` Only works with mocked members that return `Task` derived results.

Answer (score 14):

I've hit this error message several times over the past few weeks and keep forgetting how I fixed it, so I'm writing it here in the hope it helps someone.  Each time it was because I was being daft and was passing in an object/type when the method I was setting up expected a **list** of objects/types.

Comment: I've hit this error message several times over the past few weeks and keep forgetting how I fixed it, so I'm writing it here in the hope it helps someone. Each time it was because I was being daft and was returning an IEnumerable<T> when the method I was setting up returned a List<T>.

Comment: Had refactored and the mock was returning a List but the new method was just returning an item. Worst error message ever...

Comment: My similarly daft error was to return `Client` instead of `ClientSummary`.  Like others, it's just returning the wrong type - a.k.a. being daft : )

Comment: Similar (wrong type) issue, except I was returning a mock and forgot to say mock. Object.

Answer (score 8):

Another option for this error is because `ReturnsAsync` is only available for methods that return a `Task<T>`. For methods that return only a Task, either of the following options can be used:

```
mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)))


mock.Setup(arg=>arg.DoSomethingAsync()).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In my case, this was the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you have included the namespace for the interface when you new up the Mock.

Answer (score 0):

A different scenario for my issue, the API being mocked returns a dynamic object and I tried to set up the mock to return a dynamic object.

Something doesn't like that, and it worked when returning an object instead of dynamic.